# Transform tag only if other kind of tag will follow

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'd like to amend an existing xsl file so that the tag `<Empty>` in the source document is only transformed if there will follow another sibling which is not this tag. A kind of truncate of these tags to the end.

Currently I have:

```
...
<xsl:template match="Expression">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Empty">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Can this be achieved with xslt?

Sample input

```
<root>
  <dummy1>Test1</dummy1>
  <Empty>Empty1</Empty>
  <Empty>Empty2</Empty>
  <dummy2>Test2</dummy2>
  <Empty>Empty3</Empty>
  <Empty>Empty4</Empty>
  <Empty>Empty5</Empty>
</root>
```

desired output:
`Test1Empty1Empty2Test2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding up a new answer ..

If this is your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <dummy>test</dummy>
  <Empty>copy-this</Empty>
  <Empty>copy-this1</Empty>
  <dummy>test</dummy>
  <Empty>copy-this</Empty>
  <Empty>copy-this1</Empty>
  <dummy>test</dummy>
  <Empty>donot-copy-this2</Empty>
  <Empty>donot-copy-this2</Empty>
</root>
```

XSLT: sample code..

```
  <xsl:template match="dummy">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Empty[following-sibling::*[name()!='Empty']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Output:

```
testcopy-thiscopy-this1testcopy-thiscopy-this1test
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post a small input sample and the corresponding result you want to create with XSLT. There is a sibling axis in XPath so doing e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Empty[following-sibling::*[1][not(self::Empty)]]">
  <!-- now transform here as needed -->
</xsl:template>
```

matches any `Empty` elements followed by another element that is not an `Empty` element but I am not sure that is all you need and what you want to do inside of the template.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed Input XML as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <dummy1>test</dummy1>
  <Empty>do-not-copy</Empty>
  <Empty>copy-this1</Empty>
  <dummy2>test</dummy2>
  <Empty>do-not-copy-this2</Empty>
</root>
```

In the above XML .. 2nd element `<Empty>do-not-copy</Empty>` has immediate next sibling as `<Empty>copy-this1</Empty>` so it should not be selected. where as 3rd element is followed-by `<dummy2/>` so it should be copied ..

 and 5th element is `<Empty>copy-this2</Empty>` it's not followed by any tag .. so it should be dropped as well :)

**this is the XSL code for that:**

```
  <xsl:template match="Empty[following-sibling::*[1][name()!='Empty']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Semms to be misunderstood: the last empty tag should be ignored because there is no other following one which is different to empty.

Comment: @stracktracer, dude, `<Empty>Empty1</Empty>` is not copied because it is followed by `<Empty>Empty2</Empty>` .. According to your requirement **it shouldn't be copied** ..

Comment: Where do you read this? I read and I meant only to print out the content of `<Empty>` if there are other kinds of tags following after it as siblings. I posted a working alternative as other answer.

Comment: @stracktracer, oh! I finally understood your requirement .. ohk editing the answer .. along with a robust xml.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the proposed solutions to the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Empty[following-sibling::*[not(self::Empty)]]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

which seems to work.